# Regular curve and the implicit function theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Given $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t)):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ be a smooth regular curve. i.e. $\gamma'(t)\neq0$. Is there any relationship between such a curve and the implicit function theorem? In particular, is it true that at any point in which the curve is regular, it can be represented as a graph of a function $x=x(y)$ or $y=y(x)$, at least locally?

I am asking because if e.g. $x'(t_0)\neq0$ then the tangent at this point is not parallel to the y-axis, and at least graphically, it seems like it would imply that there is a neighborhood of $(x(t_0),y(t_0)) $ in which the curve is a function $y=y(x)$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should apply the implicit function theorem to the function $x:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let us assume that $x$ is continuously differentiable.

First, pick any $t\in I$. Then by the implicit function theorem, if $x'(t)\neq 0$, there exists an open interval $U\subseteq I$ containing $t$, such that $x: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is invertible with continuously differentiable inverse. Let's call this inverse
$$x^{-1}: x(U) \rightarrow U.$$
Then notice that we have
$$y(t) = y(x^{-1}(x(t))), \qquad \forall t \in U.$$
Hence we have that $\gamma$ is locally (on $U$) the graph of the function
$y \circ x^{-1}$.

For example, take the circle $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$. Then for all $t \in (0,\pi)$, we have $x(t) \in (-1,1)$. Therefore, by the above derivation, $\gamma$ given by the graph of the function
$$
y = \sin(\cos^{-1}(x)), \qquad \forall x \in (-1,1),
$$
which is the upper half of the circle (not including the two points intersecting the $x$-axis.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more related to the inverse function theorem. Supposing, as you did, that $x'(t_0)$ is different of $0$, than exists a neighborhood $J\subset\mathbb{R}$ where $x$ is invertible and both $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are continuosly differentiable. Therefore, for all $(u,v)\in U = \gamma(J)$, we can put $v$ in function of $u$ by $v(u) = y(x^{-1}(u))$, where $v$ will ber constinuosly differentiable (In our case it will be smooth also).

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you!